# Annotate and filter nested resources

Tags: django, tastypie

I've created a nested resource that I'm posting some data to and filtering based on what I post.  What I need to do in addition to that is annotate my data as well which I can't seem to figure out.

Is there a way to get a query similar to the following in a nested resource?

```
Collection.objects.filter(picture__type__name__in=request.POST.getlist('pictures[]')).annotate(total=Count('picture')).filter(total=len(request.POST.getlist('pictures[]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to make an annotated query on each individual item in the initial collection you should look into using [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

The example from the docs that might help you on your way:

```
Blog.objects.extra(
    select={
        'entry_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_entry WHERE blog_entry.blog_id = blog_blog.id'
    },
)
```